# How to apply a function on every pair of rows of a Matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I'm new to matlab and working with matrix and I'm kinda confused.

I'm supposed to make a `m` x `n` matrix called `M` and it's elements are `-1`, `1` and `0`.

I need to write a function called `d(x,y)` which returns `1` if `x = -1` and `y = 1`. And returns `0` otherwise.

and another function which calculates the sum of d(m(i,j),m(k,j)) in every column:

[image: func]

Please read the comment for an example.

How to find the sum?

I know basic programming but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Check [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/378974-how-to-find-hamming-distance#answer_301769), where A is your matrix

Comment: Suppose M = [-1 0 -1; 1 -1 -1; 0 1 1]. If I calculate the sum for the 1st row and 2nd row it's Sum of d(m(1,j),m(2,j) for j from 1 to 3 which is d(m11,m21) + d(m12,m22) + d(m13,m23) = d(-1,1) + d(0,-1) + d(-1,-1) = 1+ 0 + 0 =1 .I'm not sure if it's same as the hamming distance though.Then I want to write the code of this sum for every pair of rows and have the answer in a matrix but I don't know how.

Comment: Why is `d(0,-1)` 0?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Because d(x,y) returns 1 only if (x=-1 & y=1). Also I edited my question a bit.

Comment: Right okay, have you tried @OmG's answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nchoosek` for selction:

```
comb = nchoosek(1:size(m,1), 2);
result = zeros(1, length(comb)); % allocate the memory
% you can run some techniques to run a function on each row of comb
% which is mentinoned in other posts instead of the following code
for i = 1:length(comb)
    result(i) = sum(abs(m(comb(i,1), :) - m(comb(i,2), :)) == 2);
end
```