# Does the order of inputs matter in MATLAB functions?

Tags: matlab, function, commutativity

I have a function called `f(x,y)`, which returns `1` when both `x = -1` and `y = 1`, and `0` otherwise.

I want to apply it on every pair of the same column elements of a matrix. I want to know if I have to repeat it the other way? or does it work the same for `f(y,x)`? I mean does it return `1` if one of the elements is `-1` and the other is `1` anyway or it has to be in order?

Comment: Yes, I’m general the order matters. But whether it matters for this particular function we don’t know unless you show the function. You can do the test yourself: swap the inputs and see if it returns the same value,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how the function `f` is defined.

- If it's symmetric with respect to the inputs, i.e. "one of them" needs to be `-1` and "the other" `1`, it would work without change for reverse inputs.
- If the function was defined such that both "the first" input must be `-1` and "the second" must be `1` - the result might be different when the argument order is switched.

For example, this is a "symmetric" way to define `f`:

```
function out = f(x,y)
  out = ~(x+y);
end
```

And this is an "asymmetric" way:

```
function out = f(x,y)
  out = (x == -1) && (y == 1);
end
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that, yes, the order matters, unless the function is written such that it doesn’t. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo ...or as I said in the very beginning - "it depends". :)

Comment: How to code && in a symmetric way? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @FreeSoul If you want it to be "symmetric" just use the top suggestion. If you insist, you can do `out = ((x == -1) && (y == 1)) || ((x == 1) && (y == -1))`. Note that if `x` or `y` are arrays, you need to use `&` instead of `&&`.

Comment: I would "insist", because your symmetric example doesn't give the desired result for other input pairs where `x+y==0`, for instance by the original definition `f(-4,4)` should return `0` but would return `1` here. Probably easier to just be explicit with something like `max(x,y) == 1 && min(x,y) == -1`.

Comment: @Wolfie You're right. However, [from a related question by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51579179/3372061) we learn that this matrix only contains `-1, 0, 1` elements.